# Apple Silicon M1 Pro + Simulator

Tags: xcode, simulator, microchip

Bought a new Macbook Pro on the M1 chip. Downloaded Xcode, installed the CLI. I run an empty test project on simulator iphone 14/pro/SE ...
But they all start with a black screen.

[image]

I restarted my computer, reinstalled Xcode 14.3 from xcodereleases.com. Any ideas what else can be done to fix it?